# How to configure phpmyadmin under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, mysql

I've installed `LAMP` but when I put in `apache.conf` this line as is in instruction `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` and trying to restart apache I get follow error:

```
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart 
* Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                      [fail] 
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 222 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open   configuration file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I've checked in `/etc/phpmyadmin` and I don't have such a file `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
```

My question is do I need to download it from somewhere or I must create one and put something in it? Doesn't this file come with installation of LAMP?

Update with error `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

```
Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini with new version
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package php5-mysql (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up javascript-common (11) ...
dpkg: error processing package javascript-common (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of phpmyadmin:
phpmyadmin depends on php5-mysql | php5-mysqli | php5-mysqlnd; however:
Package php5-mysql is not configured yet.
Package php5-mysqli is not installed.
Package php5-mysqlnd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php5 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
php5-mysql
javascript-common
phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed phpmyadmin?

Seems to me like you missed it. It's not a part of the LAMP stack per se, but an administration tool for configuring MySQL (which is written in php).

You would need to do `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` as per [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/phpmyadmin.html). After completing this step, you should be able to access phpMyAdmin.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Please check my updated question what I get when I perform `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

Comment: It would seem you need to run `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` also..

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-mysql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
`